# How to define edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

When I use absolute position for the edges, I get  almost intersecting arrows. Here is my code. Kindly help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [
      node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
      >=stealth,
      scale=0.8,
      transform shape
    ]
    \node[block] at (2,3) (Incompetent Reflux Mechanism){Incompetent Lower esophageal sphincter};
    \node[block] at (2,0) (Gastric content into esophagus and beyond){Gastric content into esophagus and beyond};
    \node[block] at (-2, -3) (Symptoms){Symptoms};
    \node[block] at (6, -3)(Mucosal damage){Mucosal damage};
    \node at (2,-3){and or};
    \begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
    \draw[->] (2,3) -- (2,0);
    \draw[->] (2,0) -- (-2,-3);
    \draw[->] (2,0) -- (6,-3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{frame}
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a complete, compilable document rather than a fragment. Especially since this fragment, even if pasted into a simple wrapper won't compile (due to the irrelevant `\end{frame}`.)

Comment: `\draw[->] (2,3) -- (2,0);` draws an arrow between two coordinates and not between two nodes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally the `node`s are written like this:

```
\node[<options>] at (<x>,<y>) (<label>) {<content>};
```

You have already `label`led the nodes but those label are long. Make them short: `(Mechanism)` instead of `(Incompetent Reflux Mechanism)` Now you can draw the arrows with the help of these labels:

```
\draw[->] (Mechanism) -- (Gastric);
```

will draw an arrow between the node labelled `Mechanism` and `Gastric`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{block/.style ={rectangle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
      node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
      >=stealth,
      scale=0.8,
      transform shape
    ]
    \node[block] at (2,3)  (Mechanism){Incompetent Lower esophageal sphincter};
    \node[block] at (2,0)  (Gastric){Gastric content into esophagus and beyond};
    \node[block] at (-2, -3) (Symptoms){Symptoms};
    \node[block] at (6, -3) (Mucosal){Mucosal damage};
    \node at (2,-3){and or};
    \begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
    \draw[->] (Mechanism) -- (Gastric);
    \draw[->] (Gastric.south) -- (Symptoms.north);
    \draw[->] (Gastric.south) -- (Mucosal.north);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make arrows to turn by

\draw[->] (Gastric.south) -- ++(0,-1) -| (Symptoms.north);

`(Gastric.south) -- ++(0,-1)` draws a line from `Gastric.south` down to a length of 1cm and `-| (Symptoms.north);` draws an arrow that bends towards `Symptoms.north`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{block/.style ={rectangle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
      node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
      >=stealth,
      scale=0.8,
      transform shape
    ]
    \node[block] at (2,3)  (Mechanism){Incompetent Lower esophageal sphincter};
    \node[block] at (2,0)  (Gastric){Gastric content into esophagus and beyond};
    \node[block] at (-2, -3) (Symptoms){Symptoms};
    \node[block] at (6, -3) (Mucosal){Mucosal damage};
    \node at (2,-3){and or};
    \begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
    \draw[->] (Mechanism) -- (Gastric);
    \draw[->] (Gastric.south) -- ++(0,-1) -| (Symptoms.north);
    \draw[->] (Gastric.south) -- ++(0,-1) -| (Mucosal.north);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if my content is high in the box ,how can i give \newline syntax

Comment: @KBM: Add `align=center` to node options and then use `\\ ` to break the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw the line between two nodes that you label instead of two coordinates.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [
  node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
  >=stealth,
  scale=0.8,
  transform shape
]   
\node(a1) at (0,0) {Hello};
\node(a2) at (2,0) {World};
\draw[->] (a1) -- (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ Speravir,if my content is high in the \node ,how can i give \newline for my sentence